# Find the distance of a point to the $z$ axis.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the distance the from the point $(3,2,-1)$ to the $z$ axis.

Here is what I have in mind but I'm not sure.

The $z$ axis is the collection of points $(0,0,z_0)$ where $z_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. We are looking for the minimum distance between  $(3,2,-1)$, hence what we are looking for is:

$$\text{min}\{d((3,2,-1),(0,0,z_0))\}=\text{min}\{\sqrt{3^2+2^2+(-1-z_0)^2}\}=\sqrt{3^2+2^2+(-1)^2}=\sqrt{14}$$

Would this be correct? It seems like I'm just finding the distance from the point to the origin. Studying, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are slightly off.

You are correct about the $z$ axis being made up of points of the form $(0,0,z_0)$. So $z_0$ can be any real. Which real number makes it closer to a point whose $z$ coordinate is $-1$? $-1$ itself. So if you consider $(0,0,-1)$, which is a point in the $z$ axis by your definition, you get a point whose distance from your point is $\sqrt{(3-0)^2+(2-0)^2+(-1-(-1))^2} = \sqrt{13}$

Answer (score 1):

The distance from a point $(a,b,c)$ to the $z-$axis is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

Imagine projecting the point into the $xy-$plane and finding the distance to the origin.

Comment: Thanks, visualizing was a bit hard but I got the visual what you were saying.